# Looping the if statement to restart a service in case of failure

Tags: c#, methods, service

I have a code where I am checking if the service that I am passing as a parameter in the method is running then stop it & start it with an interval of 10 seconds, basically it's just a restart method. However, is it possible to use a loop with a timer to so that in case after stopping if the service is not starting keep trying to start back up until it is running back again.

The library I am using is System.ServiceProcess

Here's the method I've so far.

```
public static bool RestartService(string serviceName)
{
    bool result = false;
    using (ServiceController controller = new ServiceController(serviceName))
    {
        try
        {
            if (controller.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
            {
                controller.Stop();
                controller.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped,
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            }

            if (controller.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
            {
                controller.Start();
                controller.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running,
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            }

            if (controller.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error($"RestartService {serviceName} failed, 
                exception_message: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I suppose its possible, however I would recommend this method runs on a background thread if you do add a for loop

Comment: You could just change your first two`if` statements to `while` statements if you want it to keep trying (and then the third `if` is unnecessary - you can just set `result = true;`). Is that your question, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*is it possible to use a loop with a timer to so that in case after stopping if the service is not starting keep trying to start back up until it is running back again.*

The method can be called from a `Timer` (which is probably a good idea so that it runs in the background).

Converting your code to do retrying until success is as simple as changing `if` to `while`:

```
public static bool RestartService(string serviceName)
{
    bool result = false;
    using (ServiceController controller = new ServiceController(serviceName))
    {
        try
        {
            while (controller.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
            {
                controller.Stop();
                controller.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped,
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            }

            while (controller.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
            {
                controller.Start();
                controller.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running,
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            }

            result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error($"RestartService {serviceName} failed, 
                exception_message: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```